# Flutter Anyline plugin crashing app in release mode when camera opens

Tags: flutter, anyline, mrz

I am using this plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/anyline_plugin/changelog
It's working and scanning fine in debug mode but in release mode, when the button is clicked, it asked for permission, when permission was granted suddenly app crashed and closed without any error in the console. I have added permission for the camera in Android.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

==>Solved

==> use these guard-rules in your app-level build.gradle

`-keep public class * { public protected *; }`